# Question regarding addition of subspaces of a Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a vector space $V=R[x,4]$ (polynomials with degree $\leq4$).

Let $Q$ be a subspace of $V$ with the following property: $Q=R[x,4|p(1)=0]$ ($1$ is a root of a polynomial)

Let $T$ be another subspace of $V$ with the following property: $T=R[x,4|p(3)=0]$ ($3$ is a root of a polynomial)

Now, $Q\cap T$ is the intersection of these two subspaces. Thus, we are only considering polynomials in $R[x,4]$ which are equal $0$ if $x = 1$ or $x = 3$.

My question is: what is the meaning of $Q+T$? I know that it spans the whole $R[x,4]$ because the vector span of the basis of $Q+T$ = the basis of $R[x,4]$. But it's not intuitive for me that any polynomial from $R[x,4]$ is also in $Q+T$.

Is there an example which would make this addition more intuitive and obvious?

Comment: What's the question?  You say that you know that $Q+T$ spans all of $V$, so what are you asking?

Comment: It's not intuitive for me how vectors from Q and T can make any vector from V. I understand that their bases match, thus, it is true. But I'd like to get some example which would make it more obvious and intuitive.

Comment: So...just work examples.  For instance, $x-1\in Q$ and $x-3\in T$ implies that the constant $2$ is in $Q+T$.  That quickly shows that all constants are in the span.  But then, starting from any polynomial in $V$ we can subtract a constant to get it into $Q$ or $T$.

Comment: Thanks, now that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$$R[x,4]=\left\{\left.\sum_{n=0}^4a_nx^n\right|a_0,\ldots,a_4\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$
Since $Q=R[x,4|p(1)=0]$ and $T=R[x,4|p(3)=0]$, it is possible to show that
$$Q=\left\{\left.\sum_{n=1}^4b_n\left(x^n-1\right)\right|b_1,\ldots,b_4\in\Bbb R\right\};$$
$$T=\left\{\left.\sum_{n=1}^4c_n\left(x^n-3^n\right)\right|c_1,\ldots,c_4\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$
Now, note that any element of $R[x,4]$ can be written as
$$(*) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \sum_{n=0}^4a_nx^n=\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^4a_n\left(x^n-1\right)+\left(a_1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^4a_n\right)(x-1)}_{\displaystyle\in Q}+\underbrace{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^4a_n\right)(x-3)}_{\displaystyle \in T}.$$
We can get some intuition using $(*)$ to construct some examples. For instance,
\begin{align}
29&=\underbrace{\frac{29}{2}(x-1)}_{\displaystyle\in Q}-\underbrace{\frac{29}{2}(x-3)}_{\displaystyle\in T};\\
x+1&=\underbrace{2(x-1)}_{\displaystyle\in Q}-\underbrace{(x-3)}_{\displaystyle\in T},
\end{align}
and so on.